# PHP - Looping through JSON Array without "string"?

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I have question. I have an JSON Array

Here's the JSON: http://pastebin.com/raw/XEzAEdfg

How could I loop it through? Here's what I've tried at the moment:

```
$output = json_decode($result2);
foreach($output as $SuiFag){
    echo $SuiFag->aaData[6];
}
?>
```

Comment: What are you expcting from echo `$SuiFag->aaData[6];`?  Can you show us the full $output array and remove all that is duplicated

Comment: The value of $SuiFag will be all the items in "aaData" on the first pass and whatever else is in that JSON array after that.  So you will either need another foreach to loop through those or some other approach.

Comment: @Matt, it should echo that 6th line. So it would be that 0.21..

Comment: @JacobSeen change it to  `echo $SuiFag->aaData[0][6];` and let me know if you get `0.2123493403`. Hopefully you should and I will add an answer to what you need to add.

Comment: @JacobSeen your description is not very clear, any way I made some assumptions and I give you an answer below, the json structure must be a valid object.

Comment: I've edited first post. Added full JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the aaData array then output the 6th line. The below will output the 6th line of every aaData array

```
$output = json_decode($result2);
foreach($output as $SuiFag) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($SuiFag);$i++) {
        echo $SuiFag[$i][6] . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Of course you can add a third loop if you want to echo each item of the array out

```
$output = json_decode($result2);
foreach($output as $SuiFag) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($SuiFag);$i++) {
        for($x=0; $x<count($SuiFag[$i]);$x++) {
            echo $SuiFag[$i][$x] . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Since you have only the aaData in your json you could shorten this down to but above allows for further items in your json array:

```
foreach($output->aaData as $SuiFag) {
    for($i=0; $i<count($SuiFag);$i++) {
        echo $SuiFag[$i] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

*Credits to lamp76*

Comment: Nothing happens :/ empty.

Comment: @JacobSeen can you check that your json array is actually a json array? paste the full `$result2` to http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yeah, it is. I've already checked it :). I just added here a piece. I can add everything.

Comment: Ahh okay. give me a sec

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you data json data should be an object attribute named "aaData" of type array so only a [ character should be there, and { and } should define the start and the end of the json object(traling comma is not allowed):

```
$result2='{
   "aaData": [
         "Knife",
         "/id/1676/",
         "★ Karambit | Stained (Field-Tested)<\/a>",
         "234.87",
         "224.85",
         "5907380460<\/a>",
         "0.2123493403<\/a>",
         "Inspect<\/a>"
      ]
}';
```

So you can use direct object attribute access (you need foreach to scan an array but not the attribute of an object):

```
$output = json_decode($result2);
echo $output->aaData[6];
```

OR 
if your json structure is something like this:
allowed):

```
$result2='{
    ...
   "aaData": [
        [
         "Knife",
         "/id/1676/",
         "★ Karambit | Stained (Field-Tested)<\/a>",
         "234.87",
         "224.85",
         "5907380460<\/a>",
         "0.2123493403<\/a>",
         "Inspect<\/a>"
        ],
        ...
    ]
}';
```

then your code should be:

```
$output = json_decode($result2);
foreach($output->aaData as $SuiFag){
    echo $SuiFag[6];
}
```

TO print every 6th element of every element of the array "aaData";